# Video scope shows only a limited number of videos

Tags: ubuntu-touch, video

My videos scope seems to have maxed out somehow - new videos don't appear unless I delete others. I can get them through the gallery app, but is there another nicer way? And is there a way to remove that limit?

Comment: I am not knowledgeable about unity scopes that much, but my first guess would be that they read `locate`'s database or something similar. Try running `sudo updatedb` and then searching videos again